# Should all words be capitalized when separated by an ampersand in a bullet list?

Tags: capitalization, lists

Should all words be capitalized when separated by an ampersand in a bullet list?

e.g.,

- Department of Chemistry
- Physics & Chemistry seminars <--- ?

Comment: Bullet lists are for audiences. What do your audiences think? Are they extra into capitalization or typography? Normally absence of obvious inconsistencies is good enough for something that won't be seen longer than a few seconds.

Comment: @JohnLawler  Ok, that's perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand is merely an abbreviation for the word "and". In your example "Physics" and "Chemistry" would normally be capitalised regardless of the ampersand. Consider the following

> In grade xx of primary school students are taught to
>
> - Count up to 100
> - Add & subtract whole numbers
> - Read & write
>
> etc

It is not appropriate to capitalise "subtract" or "write".

Comment: It's my understanding that ampersand represents, but is not the same as, "and".  And why would "Physics" and "Chemistry" would normally be capitalised?

Comment: Certainly the ampersand is much less formal. Physics and Chemistry are subject names, so they often get capitalised. I studied Physics (with a capital), but there was chemistry (no capital) between the two lovers.

Comment: There is a confusion here between the names of academic disciplines, which are common nouns and so **not** capitalised, and the names of particular university departments, which are proper names and so capitalised.

Comment: @jsw29, in my experience subject names are capitalised. If students study physics in Year 10 in secondary school, it may be as part of a general science curriculum. If students study Physics in year 10 of secondary school, it is a subject with that name.

Comment: @Peter, now I see what the misunderstanding is: you are using the word *subject* for structured courses in formal educational institutions, rather than for academic disciplines. You are indeed right that e.g. *Physics* can be the title of a course (subject in one sense of that word) and that it is then capitalised, just as it is in a book title. However, physics can also be said to be the subject (in another sense of that word) that one is interested in, or that one has spent some time studying, apart from any formal education; when used in that sense, it is not capitalised.